# facebook php sdk 5 codeginiter issue with autoloader

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I downloaded updated php sdk 5 and want to integrate it with my codeigniter setup. I placed the sdk in **third_party** folder and trying to create login url using my controller.

**Controller**

```
require(APPPATH.'third_party/facebook-php-sdk-v5/autoload.php');
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
class Facebook extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id'     => '*********',
        'app_secret' => '*********',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
        ]);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $permissions = ['email', 'public_profile']; // optional
        $callback = 'http://localhost/fblogin/loggedin.php';
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
        echo $loginUrl;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: LogicException

Message: Illegal value passed (no array or string given)

Filename: /path/application/third_party/facebook-php-sdk-v5/autoload.php

Line Number: 76

Backtrace:

File: /path/application/third_party/facebook-php-sdk-v5/autoload.php
Line: 76
Function: spl_autoload_register

File:/path/application/controllers/Facebook.php
Line: 2
Function: require

File: /path/localit/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

What could be the issue with it. I have complete folder structure copied to third_party from my localhost php installation. Same setup is working perfectly on localhost but while on codeigniter it just don't let the codeigniter even load it.

Comment: The SDK also has a class named `Facebook`, although name-spaced - but I think you should call your own class something else.

Comment: @C its something, it can't predict which folder to pick to autoload required files

Comment: @CBroe spl_autoloader_register has something to do with it.do you know how ?